# Dynamics CRM for Phones and Tablets Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$1n8' of null

Tags: android, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

We have upgraded from CRM 2013 to 2016 On-premises (8.1.0.359), everything works fine for us except that we are experiencing random errors on ***CRM for Phones and Tablets***.[image: Error on Android device].

**Error log:**

```
<CrmScriptErrorReport> 
    <ReportVersion>1.0</ReportVersion> 
    <ScriptErrorDetails> 
        <Message>Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property &apos;$1n8&apos; of null</Message> 
        <Line>1</Line> 
        <URL>/nga/scripts/Microsoft.Crm.Client.Core.Framework.js</URL> 
        <CallStack> 
            <Function>anonymous</Function> 
        </CallStack> 
    </ScriptErrorDetails> 
    <ClientInformation> 
        <BrowserUserAgent>Mozilla&#47;5.0 &#40;Linux&#59; Android 5.0.2&#59; SM-G530H Build&#47;LRX22G&#59; wv&#41; AppleWebKit&#47;537.36 &#40;KHTML, like Gecko&#41; Version&#47;4.0 Chrome&#47;45.0.2454.95 Mobile Safari&#47;537.36 OAuth MSAuthHost</BrowserUserAgent> 
        <BrowserLanguage>en-GB</BrowserLanguage> 
        <SystemLanguage>undefined</SystemLanguage> 
        <UserLanguage>undefined</UserLanguage> 
        <ScreenResolution>360x640</ScreenResolution> 
        <ClientName>Mobile Tablet</ClientName> 
        <ClientTime>2016-10-26T17:09:07</ClientTime> 
    </ClientInformation> 
    <ServerInformation> 
        <OrgLanguage>1033</OrgLanguage> 
        <OrgCulture>1033</OrgCulture> 
        <UserLanguage>1033</UserLanguage> 
        <UserCulture>1033</UserCulture> 
        <OrgID></OrgID> 
        <UserID></UserID> 
        <CRMVersion>8.1.0.359</CRMVersion> 
    </ServerInformation> 
</CrmScriptErrorReport>
```

We have tried different things like disabling our custom java scripts but nothing works for us so far!

**Observations:**

- The issue occurs when we load the application for the very first time
  and tap somewhere like tapping home button or tapping on dashboards.
- Next it occurs when we minimize the application and opens it again
  and tap somewhere like tapping home button or tapping on dashboards.

Comment: Check if the app works at all by creating a new organization, keep it empty, then wipe and reinstall the app, and connect to this new organization. I suspect it won't work (latest version is FUBAR, all our customers have issues), in that case all you can do is open a support ticket

Comment: I have created a new online test CRM instance and the mobile app is working fine!

Comment: We are having the same issue but the error message is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property &apos;$zr&apos; of undefined". We also have the CRM 2016 on-prem but we didn't perform an upgrade.